# SessionFactory.openSession(Connection) in Hibernate 4

Tags: java, hibernate

I am pumping existing JDBC connection using `SessionFactory.openSession(Connection)`. Now in 4.0 this method is not available. Which method should I use for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [SessionFactory.withOptions()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#withOptions%28%29) and [SessionBuilder.connection(Connection connection)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionBuilder.html#connection%28java.sql.Connection%29).

**SessionBuilder connection(Connection connection)**

> Adds a specific connection to the session options
>
> **Parameters**:
> *connection* - The connection to use.
>
> **Returns**: this, for method chaining

Example:

```
SessionBuilder sb = SessionFactory.withOptions();
Session session = sb.connection(connection).openSession();
```

Comment: @Pau Kiat Wee Thank you, your answer helped me add connection pool into existing app without much effort

Comment: It may be a version thing, but withOptions() to me is shown as a non-static method. In this case, you need to create an instance of SessionFactory.

Comment: @PauloMerson - agreed. This example (especially since it is the accepted answer) should be updated to make it clear that withOptions() is NOT a static method.