# How i must set my own connection to hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

i have my own Database Handler and my connection pool and i just want set "my own created before" connection to hibernate.

if i must use ConnectionProvider, i have some problems with it,
do i must still configure properties like "hibernate.connection.driver_class" or "hibernate.connection.username" in hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: i read so much posts on different forums but i'm still confused, somebody help me please!

Comment: You can configure JNDI dataSource to hibernate. Read this article - http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=353736&seqNum=4

Comment: i said "my own created before" connection! the connection is ready, is there any way to set it to hibernate???
i don't want to use a new connection pool

Answer (score 0):

version 3

```
Connection conn = ...;
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(conn);
```

Comment: this method is not available on hibernate 4 but i found this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731266/sessionfactory-opensessionconnection-in-hibernate-4
thanx