# Get Hibernate session from JDBC Connection object?

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, hibernate-session

I have a `JDBC Connection` object which I want to convert into `Hibrenate Session`.

Is there any way by which I can achieve this?

I am tried googling, but I'm getting result vice versa.

Comment: Got my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731266/sessionfactory-opensessionconnection-in-hibernate-4

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();

session.doSomethingWorthwhile(new Worthwhile() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) {
    //Do something great with SQL here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `SessionFactory` to create a session with the connection. Call [`SessionFactory.openSession(Connection)`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#openSession(java.sql.Connection))

As the javadoc says, it's better to provide a custom `ConnectionProvider` (but depends on your scenario).

I've used this in the past when I had to use a connection that was opened with the username/password of each user (good old days).